# Checking for installed packages and if not found install

Tags: linux, bash, shell, yum, apt

I need to check for installed packages and if not installed install them.

Example for RHEL, CentOS, Fedora:

```
rpm -qa | grep glibc-static
glibc-static-2.12-1.80.el6_3.5.i686
```

How do I do a check in BASH?

Do I do something like?

```
if [ "$(rpm -qa | grep glibc-static)" != "" ] ; then
```

And what do I need to use for other distributions? apt-get?

Comment: Why not just make them required by your packages and have the package manager deal with all that?

Comment: It's just a simple bash install script to automate some things. :)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Try the following code :

```
if ! rpm -qa | grep -qw glibc-static; then
    yum install glibc-static
fi
```

or shorter :

```
rpm -qa | grep -qw glibc-static || yum install glibc-static
```

---

For debian likes :

```
dpkg -l | grep -qw package || apt-get install package
```

For archlinux :

```
pacman -Qq | grep -qw package || pacman -S package
```

Comment: Silent + only whole words, not just part of words

Comment: Hi all, I was using this code in something else and found that this does not differentiate partial matches. in my case (RedHat) I had a package `file-libs` installed but not `file` which was what I wanted; when I put `rpm -qa | grep -qw file || yum install -y file`, then `file` didn't install. The best solution is not to use `grep` at all. Just use something like this: `rpm --quiet --query file || yum install -y file`

Answer (score 1):

Based on @GillesQuenot and @Kidbulra answers, here's an example how to **loop over multiple packages**, and install if missing:

```
packageList="git gcc python-devel"

for packageName in $packageList; do
  rpm --quiet --query $packageName || sudo yum install -y $packageName
done
```

Comment: that would be super slow, for a large list..

Answer (score 0):

```
if [ $(yum list installed | cut -f1 -d" " | grep --extended '^full name of package being checked$' | wc -l) -eq 1 ]; then
  echo "installed";
else
  echo "missing"
fi
```

I use this because it returns installed / missing without relying on an error state (which can cause problems in scripts taking a "no tolerance" approach to errors via

```
set -o errexit
```

for example)

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this against downloaded RPMs. you can do it by.

```
rpm -Uvh package-name-version-tag.rpm
```