# Packer - sudo/su condition for builders

Tags: packer

I just started with Packer, and want to build AMI and Docker images.

Problem is - that Docker's Ubuntu image have no `sudo`, thus - build failed with an error:

> docker: /tmp/script_2085.sh: 3: /tmp/script_2085.sh: sudo: not found

Is there any way to add some "conditions" for a `shell` provisioner to run cmds with or without `sudo`, depending on `builder`?

Currently - my template have:

```
  ...
  "provisioners": [{
    "type": "shell",
    "inline": [
      "sleep 30",
      "sudo apt-get update",
      "sudo apt-get install -y nginx"
    ]
  }]
  ...
```

Add something like:

```
if which sudo; then sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y nginx; else apt-get update && apt-get install -y nginx; fi
```

Looks too weird solution... I'm sure - Packer has facility to do it in a better way.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just install `sudo` in the docker box.
You could do this one of two ways:

---

#### Running a script to install `sudo`, `only` on your docker image

You can use the `only` parameter in the provisioner to install `sudo` on an image:

```
...
"provisioners": [{
  "type": "shell",
  "inline": [
    "apt-get install sudo"
  ],
  "only": ["docker"]
},
  ... other provisioners here ...
]
...
```

More info in the packer docs, [here](https://www.packer.io/docs/templates/provisioners.html), under "Run On Specific Builds".

---

#### Installing sudo at the beginning of your provision script

At the beginning of your first provision script, add the command to install `sudo` if it is not already installed. Use the following (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12806200/5559221)):

```
dpkg -l | grep -qw sudo || apt-get install sudo
```

to check the list of installed packages and install if sudo is not present.

---

Personally, I'd be inclined to go for the first option, since it explicitly states that something should be done *only* on certain boxes. No room for confusion.

**Parting notes**

- Bear in mind that your provisioners will run in the order you define them in your packer file. So make sure you install `sudo` in the first one.
- You may also need to run `apt-get update` before you do the install.